Overriding derived virtual method in a templated class
I have the code below where I want foo to be implemented by the derived class but used within baseclass by bar methods. But I need foo to handle two cases where one of the inputs and the output type is:

class templated type T
bool

Something like this, but this mixes static and dynamic polymorphism.
template <typename R>
virtual container_t<R> foo(const R& value1, const T& value2) const = 0;

But the following does not build with T = bool as calling foo becomes ambiguous. How do I solve this?
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <template <typename> typename container_t, typename T>
class BaseClass {
public:
    virtual container_t<T> foo(const T& value1, const T& value2) const = 0;
    virtual container_t<bool> foo(bool value1, const T& value2) const = 0;

    container_t<T> bar_t() const {
        return foo(T(0), T(0));
    }
    container_t<bool> bar_bool() const {
        return foo(false, T(0));
    }
};

template <typename T>
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass<std::vector, T> {
public:
    using BaseClass<std::vector, T>::bar_t;
    using BaseClass<std::vector, T>::bar_bool;

    DerivedClass() {}

    std::vector<T> foo(const T& value1, const T& value2) const override {
        return std::vector<T>(8, value1);
    }

    std::vector<bool> foo(bool value1, const T& value2) const override {
        return std::vector<bool>(8, value1);
    }
};

int main() {

    DerivedClass<int> int_instance;
    std::cout << int_instance.bar_t().size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << int_instance.bar_bool().size() << std::endl;

    DerivedClass<bool> bool_instance;
    std::cout << bool_instance.bar_t().size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << bool_instance.bar_bool().size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

Compiler error:
1>main.cpp
1>main.cpp(15,1): error C2668: 'BaseClass<std::vector,T>::foo': ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=bool
1>        ]
1>main.cpp(9,31): message : could be 'std::vector<bool,std::allocator<bool>> BaseClass<std::vector,T>::foo(bool,const T &) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=bool
1>        ]
1>main.cpp(8,28): message : or 'std::vector<bool,std::allocator<bool>> BaseClass<std::vector,T>::foo(const T &,const T &) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=bool
1>        ]
1>main.cpp(15,1): message : while trying to match the argument list '(bool, T)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=bool
1>        ]
1>main.cpp(14): message : while compiling class template member function 'std::vector<bool,std::allocator<bool>> BaseClass<std::vector,T>::bar_bool(void) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=bool
1>        ]
1>main.cpp(45): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::vector<bool,std::allocator<bool>> BaseClass<std::vector,T>::bar_bool(void) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=bool
1>        ]
1>main.cpp(20): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'BaseClass<std::vector,T>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=bool
1>        ]
1>main.cpp(43): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'DerivedClass<bool>' being compiled


Design note : In general mixing templates (static polymorphism) and inheritance (dynamic polymorphism) is not all that common.  So try to avoid it unless you are really really sure that's the solution you need. Sometimes a pure abstract templated base may be a thing but a template base with implementation not so much (the implementation can just as easily be done in the "derived" template class)

rename the second foo to foo_bool and make it protected, you already have a public interface

Alternative: explicit template specialization, but it is twice the code https://godbolt.org/z/qTob8WaGx or 4 times the code if you split each class into two to avoid any repeating code

Actually, it seems to be more an issue of mixing overloading and template specialization than mixing static and dynamic polymorphism. And if a specific instantiation of a template class leads to such an ambiguity, it is not a good sign for the design itself.


How do I solve this?

One way would be to make the function taking a bool by value take it by non-const reference and rvalue reference instead:
virtual container_t<T> foo(const T& value1, const T& value2) const = 0;

// instead of taking the `bool` by value:
virtual container_t<bool> foo(bool& value1, const T& value2) const = 0;
virtual container_t<bool> foo(bool&& value1, const T& value2) const = 0;

... and you'll then have to override both of them.
